# java and excel question

Tags: java, excel

is it possible to create a java application that will import excel files . execute excel macros and give the output in java gui. please give any advice u can on creating such an application. i will start creating the application after your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can read Excel files and it should expose the code of the macros, too. To actually run the macros, you'll need a VBA interpreter and a COM server. I doubt that you'll be able to make this work for complex macros (see [this discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/poi-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg07845.html)).

Instead, try [JaCob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) which allows you to talk to Excel from Java. This way, you should be able to load a work sheet, have Excel run the macros for you and then, you can examine the results.

Comment: +1 I think this is the most practical solution. I don't believe POI can do much with macros (the last time I looked, you couldn't write macros with POI - but perhaps that's changed now)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this API do what you need?](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try java Excel automation,

Here is a useful link:
http://www.jacozoom.com/en_jacoZoom.shtml